# Import new Zend Framework project in Zend Studio - how?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I am trying to learn how to develop on the Zend Framework, and therefore was following this tutorial:
http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf

I managed to get to the point where I created a project using zf create project-name.

However, in Zend Studio, Any way I try - it simply will not import the project :(

It tells me "No projects found" when I do a search for existing projects in the directory
C:\Users\username\Documents\Dev\project-name

Also when I do New then select PHP-> Zend Framework Project then Create Project at existing location (from existing source)
It tells me in red:  Cannot create project content in workspace.

any ideas guys?

Comment: Are you in Zend Studio 8 or the newer version 9?

Answer (score 1):

I use Zend Studio with Zend Server, so by pointing to existing project(File-New - From existing Directory) in Apache2/htdocs dir I receive no errors and project is imported.

Answer (score 0):

to me this sounds like you want to import an existing project to Zend Studio IDE. take a look at this on how to do it:

- http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/creating_a_new_project_from_an_existing_directory.htm

note:
you could create your project via command line (zf create project-name) and then import it as described in the link.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is offline now. The new URL is http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/creating_a_new_project_from_an_existing_directory.htm